# What is the state-of-the-art annealing device for solving Ising problems?

Tags: d-wave, annealing

I understand that in addition to D-Wave's quantum annealer, there have been other unconventional (although non-quantum) Ising solvers like the one from Toshiba, Fujitsu, the Coherent Ising machine, etc.

Which of these annealers perform best on, say, the travelling salesman problem ? Has there been any demonstrated advantage for any of these (including D-Wave's) over classical approaches ?